# Show that ker($(A-\lambda_1 I)^a(A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$ = ker($(A-\lambda_1 I)^a)$ker$((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, with two of its eigenvalues equal to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_1$. Show that for any $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds:

ker($(A-\lambda_1 I)^a(A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$ = ker($(A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ \oplus \ $ker$((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$.

My solution:

To prove $(\supseteq)$, we take $u + v \in$ ker($(A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ \oplus \ $ker$((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$. Then $(A-\lambda_1 I)^a (A-\lambda_2 I)^b(u+v) = (A-\lambda_1 I)^a (A-\lambda_2 I)^b u = (A-\lambda_2 I)^b (A-\lambda_1 I)^a u = 0$.

I don't know how to prove the other direction, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you need to first prove ker($(A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ \oplus \ $ker$((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$ is well defined.   Your first direction, which probably should say $u \in \ker \big( (A-\lambda_1 I)^a\big)$ and $v\in \ker\big(A-\lambda_2 I)^b\big)$ coupled with Sylvester's Rank Inequality gives the equality of the two subspaces.  [LaTeX note: try using \ker inside the dollar signs for easier typing and rendering]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by showing that $\ker((A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ \oplus \  \ker((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$ is well defined?

Comment: You can always write $\ker((A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ +\  \ker((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$ but you can only write $\ker((A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ \oplus \  \ker((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)$ when $\ker((A-\lambda_1 I)^a)\ \cap \  \ker((A-\lambda_2 I)^b)=\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$.  As an aside, the opening line in original post should say "with two of its *distinct* eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$"

Comment: Thank you. And this is always $\{0\}$, because the eigenvalues are different?

Comment: That is the thing you need to prove

Comment: Do $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ even need to be eigenvalues? Since for every $\lambda_i$, that is not necesarilly an eigenvalue, the matrix $(A - \lambda_i I)$ is of full rank, which means that its powers have full rank.